# How do I pause audio in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a simple toggle audio function, and the audio.play() works fine but not audio.pause()

```
import track from "../assets/haydn3.wav";

const AudioPlayer = () => {
 const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const audio = new Audio(track);

  const handleTogglePlay = () => {
    if (!isPlaying) {
      audio.play();
      setIsPlaying(!isPlaying);
    } else {
      audio.pause();
      console.log("pause");
      setIsPlaying(!isPlaying);
    }
  };
```

I wrote an even simpler function and that also wouldn't work. Any known issues with .pause()?

```
const pause = () => {
    audio.pause();
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try consoling `audio.paused` before line `audio.pause();`

If `audio.paused` is `true` when you expect it to be playing, there might be an issue with the audio loading or playback.

Audio Loading: Ensure that the audio file is properly loaded before calling audio.play(). You might want to listen for the can play event before starting playback:

```
useEffect(() => {
  audio.addEventListener('canplay', () => {
    // Audio is ready to play
  });
  return () => {
    audio.removeEventListener('canplay', () => {
      // Cleanup
    });
  };
}, []);
```

You can add this useEffect hook to your component to ensure that the audio is ready for playback before calling audio.play().